# plot 1, 2 and 3 SD with stat_summary function

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is the "fun.args" function within `stat_summary` for specifying the numbers of SD I want to plot for an interval of the data mean?

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) + geom_point() + 
  stat_summary(
    fun.data= "mean_sdl", fun.args = list(mult = 1),
    geom="crossbar",color="red", size=0.5)+
  stat_summary(
    fun.data= "mean_sdl", fun.args = list(mult = 2),
    geom="crossbar",color="green")+
  stat_summary(
    fun.data= "mean_sdl", fun.args = list(mult = 3),
    geom="crossbar",color="blue")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is used to specify the number of standard deviations around your mean. To see why, you have to click through some help pages:

From the help page of `stat_summary`, you'll find that `fun.args` is used to supply arguments for the function you specified in the `fun_data` argument (here: `mean_sdl`).

Digging a bit deeper: From the help page of `mean_sdl` (or actually, the help page of `smean.sld`) we find:

> smean.sdl computes the mean plus or minus a constant times the standard deviation.

The function can be used like: `smean.sdl(x, mult=2)`, where 2 specifies the "constant" that is referred to in the quote above. In other words, `mult` refers to the width of the confidence interval in terms of standard deviations.

If you supply `mean_sdl` within `stat_summary`, the `x`-argument will automatically be filled with the data you supplied to your `ggplot`-call.

Comment: Thanks Ken! do you know how to use it for to construct a teaching example?

Comment: I guess it depends on what course you are teaching. What is it that you want to convey? I think the question you asked in the comment is a different question than you asked in the main question, and it also too broad and mainly opinion based

Comment: Probably yes Ken, then I should add a new question. Just for addressing your reply I want to explain the use of stat_summary showing the 68-95-99.7 rule,
 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule)